# Overwrite file preserving target permissions without shell invocation

Tags: permissions, file-copy

I have this situation

```
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 123 Mar  5 19:32 file-a
-rwx---rwx 1 user user 987 Mar  5 19:32 file-b
```

I would like to overwrite `file-b` with `file-a` but I would like to preserver all permissions and ownership of `file-b`.

This does not work, because it uses permissions of `file-a`

```
cp file-a file-b # << edit: this works as expected! My fault!
mv file-a file-b
```

This works, but it can be called only from shell. Imagine the situation I can call only `execve` or similar function.

```
cat file-a > file-b
```

I know, that I can execute something like

```
sh -c "cat file-a > file-b"
```

but this introduce difficulties with escaping filenames so I don't want to use this.

Is there some common command that can do this or should I write my own helper c program pro this task?

Comment: When I do `cp file-a file-b`, the permissions and ownership of `file-b` do not change. Are you sure you aren’t running `cp -p` through an alias?

Comment: You are right! I don't know how I can miss this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple command to copy a file without copying the mode is

```
dd if=file-a of=file-b
```

but then you get `dd`’s verbose status message written to stderr. 
You can suppress that
by running the command in a shell and adding `2> /dev/null`,
but then you’re back to square 1. 
If you have GNU `dd`, you can do

```
dd if=file-a of=file-b status=none
```

Comment: This is also useful. I also forget this trivial solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`rsync --inplace file-a file-b` should do what you want.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

> --inplace
>     This option changes how rsync transfers a file when the file's data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes the updated data directly to the destination file.

Comment: It seems slightly odd to call upon something like rsync from a C program (or whatever he's writing) just to preserve permissions when copying a file...

Comment: Agreed, though he seems to be looking for an option that is either shell executable or easy to call from code (without indirection like `cat file-a > file-b`).

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. It is not a "core" command but it is also nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

`man cp` says:

> For each destination file that already exists, its contents are
> overwritten if permissions allow.  Its mode, user ID, and group
> ID are unchanged unless the `-p` option was specified.

If you set `-p` then `cp` will try to keep ownership and access rights of source file instead but the default behavior is to keep those attributes of the destination file if possible.

What means "*if possible*"?

Well, if the destination file does not exist, of course it isn't possible, in that case `cp` will create a file with default ownership (current user and current user's default group) and default permissions (see also `man 2 umask`). It will not fall back to `-p` behavior on its own.

Also if the destination cannot be opened for writing by the current user, `cp` cannot work that way. In that case `cp` will either fail or if you specified `-f`, it will fall back to deleting the existing file (therefor only write access to its directory is required) and then the first case applies again.

The reason why `mv` doesn't work for your caste is because `mv` always first tries to move the file atomically using `rename` (`man 2 rename`), which will only work if the destination does not exist and source and destination are located on the same storage entity (usually that means same partition). The advantage of `rename` is that it really is treated as a single atomic operation that makes the file disappear in one place and reappear in another one with all ownership and file permissions preserved. In case that is not possible, it is documented that `mv` works exactly like

> ```
> rm -f destination_path && \
> cp -pRP source_file destination && \
> rm -rf source_file
> ```